# Can't Write to File

Tags: java, file-io

I need some help please writing the output to a file and I can't get it to work. If I use the System.out.println it works. If I create the file stream and Buffered Writer in the actual method, it creates the file but doesn't write anything to it. I'm assuming it's because my method is recursive and creates a new file every time the method calls it self again. So I created another print method and used the string value key[i] as the string parameter and it does nothing.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
 public void print(String s)throws IOException
{
    fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt", true);
    out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    try{
        out.write("From print: " + s + " ");
        out.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void generate() throws IOException
{ 
    while (k<randomWordNum())
    {
        if (randomNum() <= sumOfFreq[0])
        {
            //System.out.println(getKey[0] + " "); 
            print(getKey[i]);
            i++;
            k++;
            generate();
        }
        if (randomNum() >= sumOfFreq[i] && randomNum() <= sumOfFreq[i+1])
        {
            //System.out.println("From generate: " + getKey[i+1] + " "); 
            print(getKey[i+1]);
            i++;
            k++;
            generate();
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            generate();
        }
    }//while
}//generate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that constructor of `FileWriter` will overwrite the file. So you'll need to use a code line like this:

```
fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt", true); // true for appending
```

Also, always close a file before it goes out of scope, otherwise it might never get flushed or closed if you are unlucky...

And one more thing, assuming that is not some sort of debug/troubleshooting code, "never" catch `Exception`. If you do catch it, be sure to re-throw it asyou got it after logging or whatever you did with it. But, in general, always catch a more specific exception type.

Comment: Thank you. I added the true and put tried the out.close() below the out.write() method and it works. I will look it up but do you know how to flush it out when I stop the program and re run it?

Comment: @handro Just delete the `"out.txt"` when program is started? Or possibly keep it and print a marker line telling program was started again, if you want to keep output of several executions.

Comment: thank you for your help. I just delete it when I first run the program and I also fixed my exception. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to .close the file to make sure things get written

Comment: And flush the Writer in order to clean the written content before closing the Stream.

Comment: awesome, thank you!. I updated my code. I'm just trying to figure out how to stop overwriting it everytime with a new value. I think my problem is that it is creating a new file eveytime I call print(). I'm going to keep looking at it. I tried creating the new file writer and Bufferedwriter in the constructor when I run the main, but then I get nulls.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Generally there is no need to flush before closing, close will flush first. Just close the outermost of nested streams (it will call `close()` on the nested stream (which will call `close()` on the stream nested one deeper (etc))).